# Spring Boot Actuator on non Boot application - change endpoints basepath

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot-actuator

We develop a Spring (4.1.1) based web application and I'm trying to integrate Actuator to have some nice info out of it.

Our stack:
Spring 4.1.1

Its a non Boot application so after reading a lot of questions and articles I put togheter the following code:

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.12.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

ActuatorConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@Import(EndpointAutoConfiguration.class)
public class ActuatorConfig {


    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ManagementServerProperties myManagementServerProperties() {
        ManagementServerProperties manag = new ManagementServerProperties();
        manag.setContextPath("/actuator");

        return manag;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    // Define the HandlerMapping similar to RequestHandlerMapping to expose the
    @DependsOn("myManagementServerProperties")
    public EndpointHandlerMapping endpointHandlerMapping(Collection<? extends MvcEndpoint> endpoints) {
        return new EndpointHandlerMapping(endpoints);
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    // define the HealthPoint endpoint
    @DependsOn("myManagementServerProperties")
    public HealthMvcEndpoint healthMvcEndpoint(HealthEndpoint delegate) {
        return new HealthMvcEndpoint(delegate);
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    // define the Info endpoint
    @DependsOn("myManagementServerProperties")
    public EndpointMvcAdapter infoMvcEndPoint(InfoEndpoint delegate) {
        return new EndpointMvcAdapter(delegate);
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    // define the beans endpoint
    @DependsOn("myManagementServerProperties")
    public EndpointMvcAdapter beansEndPoint(BeansEndpoint delegate) {
        return new EndpointMvcAdapter(delegate);
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    // define the mappings endpoint
    @DependsOn("myManagementServerProperties")
    public EndpointMvcAdapter requestMappingEndPoint(RequestMappingEndpoint delegate) {
        return new EndpointMvcAdapter(delegate);
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    // define the HealthPoint endpoint
    @DependsOn("myManagementServerProperties")
    public EndpointMvcAdapter dumpMvcEndpoint(DumpEndpoint delegate) {
        return new EndpointMvcAdapter(delegate);
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    // define the MetricsEndpoint endpoint
    @DependsOn("myManagementServerProperties")
    public MetricsMvcEndpoint metricsMvcEndpoint(MetricsEndpoint delegate) {
        return new MetricsMvcEndpoint(delegate);
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    @DependsOn("myManagementServerProperties")
    public EnvironmentMvcEndpoint environmentMvcEndpoint(EnvironmentEndpoint delegate) {
        return new EnvironmentMvcEndpoint(delegate);
    }
```

With this configuration I can actually call those endpoints I declared:

```
2018-02-09 12:33:47,083 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/dump],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-02-09 12:33:47,084 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/metrics/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MetricsMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2018-02-09 12:33:47,084 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/metrics],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-02-09 12:33:47,084 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/beans],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-02-09 12:33:47,084 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/health],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke()
2018-02-09 12:33:47,084 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/info],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-02-09 12:33:47,084 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/mappings],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-02-09 12:33:47,085 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/env/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EnvironmentMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2018-02-09 12:33:47,085 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/env],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
```

What I want to achieve is to change the basepath of all those endpoints to something like **\actuator** so I can call:

```
https://mydomain:8443/myapp/api/actuator/dump
https://mydomain:8443/myapp/api/actuator/metrics
```

What I tried after looking online, given that its a non boot application, is adding this configuration ad my ActuatorConfig class:

```
@Bean
        @Autowired
        public ManagementServerProperties myManagementServerProperties() {
            ManagementServerProperties manag = new ManagementServerProperties();
            manag.setContextPath("/actuator");

            return manag;
        }
```

I tried to use `@DependsOn` annotation to make sure the myManagementServerProperties was instantiated before the Actuator endpoints but nothing changed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This has been hanging around for a bit, you might have moved on.  I've only ever changed the path in the config file, so in application.yaml I have:
management:
  context-path: /actuator
You might also consider using switching to actuator 2.x.x, as the default was changed to have the endpoints exposed at /actuator.